# Silex: Disable "redirecting to redirecting to /path/of/page/" browser output

Tags: symfony, redirect, silex

This maybe a easy question. I use `$app->redirect($route);` to redirect the user after a form has been send successfully.

However, Silex displays a "redirecting to /path/of/page/" message in the browser for a brief moment.
How can I disable this? The [redirect manual](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#redirects) doesn't offer additional parameters, nor does switching off debug mode help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to disable it. You will need to overwrite the [`RedirectResponse`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.php) class (and tell the framework to use your new class when redirecting).

Comment: I wouldn't call it "bad news", it's common in OOP and not that hard :)

Comment: Sure. I was just hoping for something prebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$app->redirect($route)`, you can just return a `RedirectResponse` with the content set to blank from your controller.

```php
$response = new RedirectResponse($route);
$response->setContent('');
return $response;
```

You could even extend `RedirectResponse` to do that automatically.

```php
class BlankRedirectResponse extends RedirectResponse {
    public function setTargetUrl($url) {
        parent::setTargetUrl($url);
        $this->setContent('');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then return it from your controller instead.

```php
return new BlankRedirectResponse($target);
```